# Why am I being given "badges"?

Tags: discussion

Why are StackExchange mods giving me ridiculous badges?

I have been given the title 'Tumbleweed'. What that suppose to mean?

Answer (score 6):

I think you are taking some of the features of the Stack Exchange network as insult, when they are not in any way shape or form meant to be seen this way.

The badges you have been given are "rewards" for activity in the community. For example, the Tumblweed badge you have been given is awarded for asking a question that has had no votes, no answers, and was viewed from few users, as reported in the [badge's description](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/badges/40/tumbleweed):

> Asked a question with no votes, no answers, no comments, and low views
>   for a week

The Editor badge, for example, is given for making your first edit to a post.

They aren't meant to offend in any way, and the majority of badges should be seen as rewards :)

You can see a full list of badges [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/badges).

Comment: The Tumbleweed badge is more a consolation badge than an award badge. It says "Your question didn't get noticed, and this is a consolation price for that." In any case, a badge is not meant to offense: They are normally thought to reward positive behavior, and never as "oh, you suxx" markers.

Answer (score 5):

Moderators don't give you badges, the system automatically awards badges for certain activities.

If you click the 'Badges' item in the main menu you can see a list of all badges, and what they mean.

The 'Tumbleweed' badge is awarded when you:

> Asked a question with no votes, no answers, no comments, and low views for a week

There isn't really anything 'ridiculous' about them, they're part of the SE engine's gamification.